# xevent profiler sql server don't show the same as sql server profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have a session that executes 4 stored procedures.

4 is shown in sql server profiler, but only 3 is shown in Xevent profiler, -and Azure Data Studio profiler.

This is the textdata from sql server profiler, that does not come up in the other profilers.
Does any one have an explanation for this?

```
declare @p3 dbo.PortTableType
insert into @p3
values (N'SEGOT')

declare @p4 dbo.PortTableType
insert into @p4
values (N'CNSHG')

declare @p5 dbo.CommodityTableType
insert into @p5
values (N'FAK')

declare @p6 dbo.ContainerTableType
insert into @p6
values
(N'DV', 40, 1, 1)
insert into @p6
values
(N'HC', 40, 1, 1)

declare @p7 dbo.CarriersTableType
insert into @p7
values (N'CMDU')
insert into @p7
values (N'COSU')
insert into @p7
values (N'EISU')
insert into @p7
values (N'HLCU')
insert into @p7
values (N'MAEU')
insert into @p7
values (N'MSCU')
insert into @p7
values (N'ONEL')
insert into @p7
values (N'OOCL')
insert into @p7
values (N'ZIMU')

declare @p13 dbo.CountriesTableType

declare @p14 dbo.CountriesTableType

declare @p16 dbo.SeaContractTableType

exec sp_executesql N'BuyRatesListCheapForCons @PortsFrom, @PortsTo, @Commodities, @Containers, @Carriers, @Date, @PortFromAlt, @Incoterm, @PortToAlt, @QuoteType, @CountriesFrom, @CountriesTo, @IncludeCosts, @ContractReferences, @CustomerID, @FCLRateLevel, @RequestCurrency 
',
N'@PortsFrom [dbo].[PortTableType] READONLY,@PortsTo [dbo].[PortTableType] READONLY,@Commodities [dbo].[CommodityTableType] READONLY,@Containers [dbo].[ContainerTableType] READONLY,@Carriers [dbo].[CarriersTableType] READONLY,@Date datetime,@PortFromAlt bit,@Incoterm nvarchar(3),@PortToAlt bit,@QuoteType nvarchar(1),@CountriesFrom [dbo].[CountriesTableType] READONLY,@CountriesTo [dbo].[CountriesTableType] READONLY,@IncludeCosts bit,@ContractReferences [dbo].[SeaContractTableType] READONLY,@CustomerID nvarchar(4000),@FCLRateLevel int,@RequestCurrency nvarchar(4000)',
@PortsFrom = @p3,
@PortsTo = @p4,
@Commodities = @p5,
@Containers = @p6,
@Carriers = @p7,
@Date = '2023-03-16 11:14:01.427',
@PortFromAlt = 1,
@Incoterm = N'EXW',
@PortToAlt = 1,
@QuoteType = N'I',
@CountriesFrom = @p13,
@CountriesTo = @p14,
@IncludeCosts = 0,
@ContractReferences = @p16,
@CustomerID = NULL,
@FCLRateLevel = 0,
@RequestCurrency = NULL
```

Comment: What's your trace definition, and what's your XEvent session definition? Incidentally that exact code looks like it's just the profiler generating pseudo-code for table valued parameters, it is not actually executed like that.

Comment: I recall XE traces will not capture large TVPs to mitigate performance impact.